# Is there a name for filled square?

Tags: word-request, mathematics, terminology

When talking about circles, a "circle" refers merely to a line in the shape of a circle, whereas "disk" (or "disc") refers to a "filled circle". Is there a similar distinction for squares or rectangles?

Comment: @Adam thanks for the tags, I seriously had no idea how to tag this.

Answer (score 3):

"disc" means "thin, flat, circular object" and is mostly applied to 3D objects. "Circle" is for 2D-ish circular things.

In math, "disc" has its own meaning; the meaning you mentioned, as well as the normal meaning.

Names of shapes cover **both** definitions you provide ("a line in the shape of X" and "filled X"), except circle (and in non-rigorous talk, they get conflated too).

Comment: What would be a natural succinct way of referring to the two variants (filled vs. not)?

Comment: As you draw the line in the shape of a circle, the resulting shape ***is*** a circle, with (semantically) blank filling. As a result you get a semantic merger.

Comment: Try using filled/solid and hollow.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost Note: "Disk" has a distinct mathematical meaning (which I'm pretty sure the question is referring to) that doesn't relate to 3D objects, but rather a circular area on a plane (i.e. 2D): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_%28mathematics%29 . But I can't think of any such term for any other shape either.

Comment: @jezW How about the distinction between _annulus,_  and _concentric circles_?  Perhaps we don't specify a name for "filled square" because topologically, that's the same thing as a disk.

Comment: @jezW A ha. Adding. (I put "mostly" because I knew I forgot that, but I didn't know what I forgot.)

Answer (score -3):

The catch-all term for these is"plane." Circular plane, square plane, rectangular plane etc.

A disk is defined as a plane bounded by a circle. Searching for the phrase "plane bounded by a square" does not yield a single word for which this is the definition.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is probably because planes are, in fact, rectangular by default. "Rectangular plane" is a redundant phrase. I can't find any nice words for a sub-section of the plane, though.

Comment: I always took "rectangular plane" to mean a *finite* plane with known bounds since, as you say, otherwise it is redundant.

Comment: In my experience (graduate school mathematics in a U.S. university), we would have called them "regions," not planes.  Rectangular region.  Triangular region.  I completely disagree with the idea that "planes" are rectangular.  Planes are infinite.

Comment: Surely you accept that there is a normal plain-english usage that makes fewer fine distinctions than a graduate-level treatise on mathematics without me needing to resort to a link to a dictionary. Also bear in mind that I myself say that planes are infinite.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The answer is the last line: "there is none"

Comment: @Yorik - I was mostly disagreeing with the statement "planes are, in fact, rectangular by default," which was not yours.  Your statement _"rectangular plane" [would be understood as] a finite plane with known bounds"_  I have slightly less issue with, although I don't think I have heard that expression before - I would expect "rectangle on a plane" or "planar rectangle."  I think the "plain English" usage of _plane_ allows for the edges to be sufficiently far away that they don't matter. I don't think you'll find a dictionary that defines a plane as having identified bounds.

Comment: Those aren't my downvotes, btw.  I have never heard the word _plane_ used the way you are using it, but I guess someone could.